# Getting the Form input value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Are there other ways to get value of an `<input>` in laravel besides `Input::get('name');` ?

Here is my route that tries and get the value

```
Route::get('delete_comment_action/{id}', function($id)/
{

    $status_Id = Input::get('status_Id');
    print_r($status_Id);
    exit();

    return Redirect::back();
});
```

here is the form that should have the data in it

```
<form action="" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name ="status_Id" value="{{$swagger->status_Id}}">
             <a href ="{{{ url("delete_comment_action/$swagger->Id") }}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>
            </form>
```

Status_Id should at least equal 1, when i try using, but instead it just displays a blank page.

```
$variable = Input::get('status_Id'); 

print_r($variable);
```

Comment: Where are you trying to `print_r` the value you get in that last code snippet?

Comment: please tell us where you are trying to print_r...

Comment: Sorry, Right underneath $status_Id = Input::get('status_Id'); @Scopey

Comment: you should use form submit not anchor tag link for delete and put form action as {{{ url("delete_comment_action/$swagger->Id") }}}"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your routes looks okay but change form submit tag instead link

```
Route::get('delete_comment_action/{id}', function($id){

    $status_Id = Input::get('status_Id');
    print_r($status_Id);
    exit();

    return Redirect::back();
});
```

> In Form view change form action and replace anchor tag link with
>   submit button

```
  <form action="{{{ url("delete_comment_action/$swagger->Id") }}}" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name ="status_Id" value="{{$swagger->status_Id}}">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete">
  </form>
```

Comment: there is a function called debug die in laravel, you can call it like : dd($value, $array, ...);

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use same route twice. You can't use it. What you have to do is separate routes like the following

This route is to show view

```
Route::get('test', function() {
    return View::make('example');
});
```

This route will handle when you submit your form

```
Route::get('newtest', function() {
    dd(Input::all());
});
```

In your `example.blade.php`

```
<form action="" method="get">
     <input type="text" name="hello">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```